# Is there a better way to term a process in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I am developing a linux app which use C#. In my app, I use the class Process to invoke another program. After call `Start()` function, if I want to term the subprocess, I can call `Kill()` method.
But `Kill()` method is like the shell command `kill -9`, which causes the child process to exit abnormally.
Is there any method like `ctrl-c` or `kill -15`?

Comment: Not familiar with linux but maybe these [remarks may help?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-7.0): `CloseMainWindow enables an orderly termination of the process and closes all windows, so it is preferable for applications with an interface. If CloseMainWindow fails, you can use Kill to terminate the process. Kill is the only way to terminate processes that do not have graphical interfaces.`

Comment: if its a console app and does it have a command to end itself? You might try sending it via StandardInput. Like `myLovelyProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");`

Comment: @Ralf No, it does not have this command. It is a blocking program when it is running. If it is running in the shell, I can use `ctrl-c` to term it. I have tried to `WriteLine("\u0003")`, and then `WaitForExit()`, but it do not work.

Comment: @Narish Thanks for your answer. I have read this article before asking this question. But It says `"Kill is the only way to terminate processes that do not have graphical interfaces."`, that is not the answer I expected.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you very much. Before I asking this question, I have read some articles which teach me to send the system call to the subprocess, but they are all on the windows platform. The article you provided is the linux version, it is useful!